# WPF remove grid from window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, grid

I have this `Grid` in my `WPF` application :

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="70" Name="BarRowDef" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Name="BarGrid" Grid.Row="0" Height="70" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF802C2C">
        <Button Content="History" Focusable="False" Width="100" Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="HistoryButton" Click="HistoryButton_Click"/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Name="MiddleGrid" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="Browser" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" LoadCompleted="Finish_Load" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>


</Grid>
```

And i want to the browser will have full screen option. So what i done is in the event Of EnterFullscreen is called is :

```
BarRowDef.Height = new GridLength(0);
```

And what happen is that the Browser start from the top of the page but in the bottom i have a white space in the size of `BarGrid`.
Any idea what can be the problem?

## Edit

This is the full `EnterFullScreenMode` method :

```
public void EnterFullScreenMode()
    {
        BarRowDef.Height = new GridLength(0);

        if (this.WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized)
        {
            this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
        }

        this.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.None;
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;

        IsFullScreen = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe setting to Visibility.Hidden can still result in some whitespace being rendered.

You can set the content of the row (BarGrid) to Collapsed, which means: "Do not display the element, and do not reserve space for it in layout".

```
BarGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

*Edit: Additional details from comments*

Also ensure the height setting removed from the RowDefinition.
Instead of:

```
<RowDefinition Height="70" Name="BarRowDef"/>
```

Use:

```
<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
```

Comment: Even with the height setting removed from the RowDefinition? e.g. instead of <RowDefinition Height="70" Name="BarRowDef" />, you would have <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

Comment: I've put your code into a test project, and setting Height to Auto for the RowDefinition, and setting the Visibility of the BarGrid to Collapsed seems to work for me. Hope it does for you too

Comment: I had some changes to do in my code and in my browser and it's work now. The code was good

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what do you mean, EnterFullscreen event of what?

You can try this:

```
BarGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

instead of:

```
BarRowDef.Height = new GridLength(0);
```